# C# Interlocked to Pointers

Tags: c#, multithreading, winapi, com, pinvoke

I'm using C# but I'm working with Unmanaged memory to aviod the GC to move the memory  and increase performance ( so no fixed) for certain buffers. Only way I found to apply Interlocked operations to C# pointers is through but it has a really bad performance

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref *(long*)(pointer));
```

In C++ we have functions like

```
long atomic_fetch_add(long * dest, long val)
```

or I can find in the Windows  libraries functions like

```
LONG InterlockedAdd(LONG volatile *Addend, LONG Value);
```

but I coudn't find any PInvoke that allows a direct call to an Atomic operation using a pointer resulting in a call with way better performance. C# will produce a poor performance call.
Any thoughts on how to be able to use a low level Interlocked, so I could to something like `Interlocked.Increment(pointer)` so it accepts my pointer and not a C# ref.

Comment: If performance is that critical, then don't use C# !

Comment: I can roughly rememerb a discussion, in wich we found out that all Field access in C# is by nature atomic. But i am unsure how far down that applies to unamanged code. But at the end of the day, creating artificial bottlenecks is what synchronisation is all about.

Comment: @Niel is probably what I'll end up doing,  problem is that all business logic is C# already,  I might end up creating a C++ library and consuming it from C#

Comment: Interlocked.Increment() is an *intrinsic* to the just-in-time compiler, like it is to the C++ compiler.  In other words, it replaces the method call with a dedicated machine code instruction.  You get `LOCK ADD oper, 1` instead of the method call.  Be sure to profile the Release build and ensure you've got Tools > Options > Debugging > General, "Suppress JIT optimization" unticked.  And make sure you are actually running 64-bit code so that (long) cast is valid, disaster if it is not.

Comment: And keep the cost of the LOCK prefix in mind.  Actual times are highly variable and depend greatly on prefetch and store buffer state.  Worst-case is a whopping 150 cycles.  There is no free lunch on modern processors.

Comment: @HansPassant How can I see the MSIL code produced , I'm actually testing it on Release using the Optimize code,  and  times for 10m records with Interlock INcrement for Interlocked.Increment( ref [variablename])  vs  Interlocked.Increment( ref *(long*) variablePointer)  are big,  like 5 sec difference. Pretty sure the second one might be doing way more

Comment: ildasm.exe will show you the MSIL of your assembly.

Comment: But as previously explained, it's the JIT'd output you want as this leads to an IL dead end (InternalCall)..